# Lock formula but allow colouring of the cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, lock, cell-format

Can anyone tell me how to lock a formula in a cell but allow the users to format the colour of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must protect the sheet, but allow formatting.

Go to the **review tab, changes group** and select **protect sheet**.

The third box down in the new window is *format cells*, so place a check mark in this box to allow users to format the cells.

Answer (score 0):

*This simple VBA code will help you to Lock Sheet with Password but allow to apply all type of formatting to Rows & Columns.*

```
Sub ProtectButAllowFormatting()
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="AA", DrawingObjects:=False, AllowFormattingCells:=True
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this code as Standard Module.
- Run Macro to Protect Sheet.
- Apply Format to Rows/Columns.
- If need Unprotect Sheet using Password.
- Alter Sheet Name & Password, if & when you 
  need.